# Making Eclipse's subversive auto update and perform a maven build on schedule?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, svn

I have right now two maven projects on an Eclipse Mars installation, Project A, and Project B, which depends on A. My idea is perform a SVN -> Update to Head of both projects, then a Maven -> Build/Install of project A, then the same for project B, so when I arrive at work everything is up to date.

I've been looking around and seems the last questions on this topic were years ago and suggested to setup a continuous integration server on the machine. My problem is that, for some reason, I'm not a machine admin (Been given an already configured installation), so it seems that installing something like Jenkins is out of the question.

So, there's any way to automate, through Eclipse, this process?

Comment: you may make this out side eclipse using only maven commands and for the schedule using your os

Comment: Huh, any advice/suggestion on how to proceed with that? I've been looking around but also haven't been able to find anything

Answer (score 0):

you may doing this outside Eclipse using the Schedule service of your OS

for  Windows:

go to Start Menu -> All Programs -> Accessories -> System tools -> Task Scheduler 
and follow the instructions [here](http://www.digitalcitizen.life/how-create-task-basic-task-wizard)

for linux:  use [crontab](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/linux-task-scheduling-crontab-explained/).

The Maven Command for SVN updat is `mvn scm:update`. you may combine this with the build command e.g. `mvn scm:update clean install`

write the commands in batch(win)/sh(linux) file according to your OS and manage the execution by the Schedule service as mentioned above.

hope this helps.